# jQuery autocomplete when passing nested attributes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am new to the rails i have form with User has_many houses, house belongs_to place
[/views/form_html_erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCYk8.png)

my jquery in users.coffee file

```
jQuery ->
$('#user_houses_place_name').autocomplete({source: ['gani', 'money']})
```

and my user.rb is [/model/users.rb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWM9x.png)

my problem is when i am autocomplete the place in user from it's not giving the options in the place text_field please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you using Coffeescript which is tab space dependent and has different syntax. You can convert your javascript to coffeescript here: http://www.js2.coffee
So your code needs to have a tab to load after the dom.

```
jQuery ->
    $('#user_houses_place_name').autocomplete source: ['gani','money']
```

FYI - 
Autocomplete will need a to know the options. So you will need to use a library and pass the list of users you want to provide as autocomplete options.

You will need to be sure to load the jQuery autocomplete module in the assets pipeline or through direct reference.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

This is rails, so you can simply load the jquery-ui gem. But be sure that the required jquery versions and ui library is loaded.

All the autocomplete work is done in javascript. So the values will be an array that you pass to javascript. The easiest is to use the gon gem (https://github.com/gazay/gon) to easily pass data to the javascript controller. In the rails controller you will define

```
gon.autocompleteUsers = User.all
```

or any condition you want to filter on the list of available users. Then call the gon array to populate the values.

Comment: thank you. i have a one doubt we need to and to add any resources to route.rb file

Comment: you will need to add a route and a controller action if you are looking to js submit. You could get away without a controller action if you are just updating or deleting. You can also define a .js matching action to do rendering options, such as ajaxing changes. Upvote my answer if useful to you.